# Crossfilter for Date for string values

Tags: crossfilter

I've a JSON model that contains strings instead of dates (the model is generated via T4TS, so I cannot change that).

The code is currently using an expanded model extending the original json, where the dates are recalculated on new fields.

I was wondering if it would be possible to apply the filters on the fields being string without adding that additional step of extending the model.

```
private makeNumeric(label: string, property: string) {
        return {
            label: label,
            key: property,
            prepareDimension: (crossfilter) => (CrossfilterUtils.makeNumeric(crossfilter, property)),
            prepareGroup: (dimension) => {

                if (!this.values[property]) {
                    var group = CrossfilterUtils.makeNumericGroup(dimension);

                    this.values[property] = group;
                }
                return this.values[property];
            },
            valuesAreOrdinal: false
        };
    }
```

I haven't used the crossfilter library much before and by looking at the documentation I can't seem to reconcile it with the code (heritage code, to put it that way).

The incoming date format looks like this: "2020-10-22T07:26:00Z"

The typescript model I'm working with is like this:

```
interface MyModel {
    ...
    CreatedDate?: string;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: It is typical to transform the data when bringing data into crossfilter, parsing numbers and dates. Is there any reason you don't want to do that here? You certainly could apply filters to string dates, but it's easier to use JavaScript Date objects and [d3-time intervals](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#time-intervals-d3-time). I'm not sure what you mean by "extending the model" - these transformations are all client-side, if that helps.

Comment: Ad un using typescript i’d rather avoid creating a new model extending the original one, just with the additional date properties. Unless there is a strong performance penalty for not doing so

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you mean by "model"... with crossfilter one writes accessors to read the data from whatever format you have. So you could convert to dates at that point. In any case, I don't think it's a performance problem to use strings so much as an expressivity problem. For example, you would have a lot of trouble working with weeks if your dates are strings, or counting the number of days between two dates.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question and probably outside the scope of SO. If you want to discuss on the [crossfilter](https://groups.google.com/g/crossfilter) or [dc.js](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/dc-js-user-group) users group, you are welcome. Not sure what kind of answer I could provide here.

Comment: Thanks. It's a Typescript model generated from a C# class via a packet called T4TS. Although it's defined as DateTime in the source it gets converted to a string by the T4TS.

Comment: The conversion is rather simple, just translating the string (e.g. 2020-10-22T07:26:00Z) into a TS Date variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual pattern in JavaScript is to loop through the data and do any conversions you need:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = new Date(d.date);
    d.number = +d.number;
});

const cf = crossfilter(data);
```

However, if this is not allowed due to TS, you can also make the conversions when creating your dimensions and groups:

```
const cf = crossfilter(data);
const dateDim = cf.dimension(d => new Date(d.date));
const monthGroup = dateDim.group(date => d3.timeMonth(date))
   .reduceSum(d => +d.number);
```

I find this a little less robust because you have to remember to do this everywhere. It's a little harder to reason about the efficiency since you have to trust that crossfilter uses the accessors sparingly, but I don't recall seeing this be a problem in practice.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried that out and although it worked fine, in the end I went with your first recommendation (expanding the TS model with Date fields to be calculated on the client from the string data coming in from the server)